# converting ObjC to Swift - UnsafePointer<Void> not convertible to struct type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm following a tutorial written in objective-c [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60998/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-2) and I've converted most things to swift already, however some lines just won't work.

for example, I've converted the following structs:

```
typedef struct {
    MessageType messageType;
} Message;
typedef struct {
    Message message;
} MessageMove;
```

to this:

```
struct Message {
    var messageType:MessageType
}
struct MessageMove {
    var message:Message
}
```

and in another line, the tutorial does the following:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
   fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {
     Message *message = (Message*)[data bytes];
     if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeMove) {
         MessageMove *messageMove = (MessageMove*) [data bytes];
     }
}
```

I've tried changing this to the following:

```
func matchDidReceiveDataFromPlayer(match: GKMatch, data: NSData, player: GKPlayer) {
    //1
    var message = data.bytes as Message //DOESNT WORK
    if (message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeGameBegin)
        //2
        var messageMove = data.bytes as MessageMove //WORKS
    }
```

but the first cast (//1) doesn't work, it says the following:

`UnsafePointer<Void> not convertible to Message`

however the second cast (//2) works. Is it because I'm doing a check on the message type in the if statement?

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because I'm doing a check on the message type in the if statement?

No. It's because, thanks to the first error on `//1`, the compiler never reaches the second line `//2` at all. You'd get the same error there, if the compiler ever reached it.

Now let's talk about the syntax. If you truly believe that `data.bytes` is the same as a Message instance, you would say:

```
let message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory
```

However, I personally would rather tend to doubt that the data you get from Objective-C would constitute a Swift struct! What went in at the Objective-C end, after all, is presumably a *C struct*, which is a different animal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. but what do you mean by `what went in at the objective-c end`? even if my `sendData()` method sends a Swift struct? or are you saying that under the hood the objective-c api is called when dealing with `NSData`?

Comment: I've never used Game Kit. I know nothing of how this method will be called or how the bytes will get into that NSData. I answered based on what you've said.